# node-serialport equivalent of remserial

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

[remserial](https://github.com/hunterli/remserial) is a program aimed at acting as a communication bridge between a TCP/IP network port and a linux serial port.

Is there a way to use the [serialport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) node package (or another) to achieve the same behavior as this command?

```
./remserial -r 10.42.0.70 -p 5001 -l /dev/remserial1 /dev/ptmx
```